# How echo out $_SESSION variable from outside login function after redirect?

Tags: php, function, authentication, echo, session-variables

I have a login script that redirects to the admin account and I want to echo out some of the session variables created within the login function but I keep on getting an 'Undefined variable' Notice.

This is my Login Script

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms1');

function login() {
    global $connect;
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["id"]             = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION["name"]       = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION["email"]      = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION["gender"]     = $row['gender'];
        $_SESSION["role"]       = $row['role'];

        header('Location: admin/index.php#/dashboard');

    } else {
        header('Location: index.php#/posts/WrongPassword');
    }
}
```

This is a snippet from my index.php file in my admin directory

```
<div class="pcard">
    <img src="../images/T1.jpg" width="100%" alt="...">
    <div class="body">
        <h4><?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?></h4>
        <h5>Admin</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you started the session with `session_start();` ?

Comment: Are you missing a session_start() somewhere. Think you will need one somewhere before the html in index.php is rendered.

Comment: Just tried it their, It worked thanks. I new I was missing something small but I didn't know what. It's being a while since I have worked with PHP sessions.

Comment: I added my comment below as an answer with a bit more detail about sessions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may not have started your session. You need to start it like this:

`session_start();`

If you do not start the session on each page you need to use `$_SESSION` variables on you will get an error like this:

`E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: _SESSION -- at line 3`

It might be worth looking at [the docs for sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)  in PHP if you are unsure about how to use them.